# The underlying provider failed on EnlistTransaction; Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, transactions, transactionscope

Please see the following exception and stacktrace which appears to indicate I'm attempting to enlist in a disposed [transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90c30fy.aspx):

> System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on
>   EnlistTransaction. ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access
>   a disposed object. Object name: 'Transaction'.    at
>   System.Transactions.Transaction.get_TransactionInformation()    at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction transaction)
>   at
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction transaction)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction transaction)
>   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(String commandText, Object[] parameters)
>   at
>   Reconciliation.Models.BillLines.BillLines.Reconciliation.Interfaces.IBillLineEntities.ExecuteStoreCommand(String, Object[])
>   at
>   Reconciliation.Models.Legacy.EntityDbEnvironment.ExecuteOracleSql(String sql)
>   at BillLineGeneratorDLL.BillExceptionChecks.**ClearOldGroupExceptions**()

The body of `ClearOldGroupExceptions()` is *entirely* encapsulated within a `TransactionScope` with its option set to `TransactionScopeOption.Required`.

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.transactions.transactionscopeoption.aspx) this should mean that:

> A transaction is required by the scope. It uses an ambient transaction
>   if one already exists. Otherwise, it creates a **new** transaction before
>   entering the scope. This is the default value.

I'm therefore stumped as to why since the current transaction has been disposed, why a new transaction wasn't created before entering the scope.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can we see something that illustrates how you are managing the transaction and this operation?

Comment: Also - is it possible you have got nested transaction scopes, and some inner scope is being rolled back (disposed without calling complete) for some reason? Due to how transaction scopes work, that would immediately doom the outer transaction(s), rolling them back immediately.

Comment: @MarcGravell - Your second comment might have some mileage in it, I'll investigate if it's possible this condition is true.  If I was to change the option to `RequiresNew` would that solve it?

Comment: that depends on how exactly they are sequenced - hence the first question